# Wait of abacus job to complete when launched from python script

Tags: python, subprocess, os.system, abaqus

I am trying to run an Abaqus script from Python through the command prompt on a Windows 8 machine.

The issue I am having is I cannot get the Python script to wait until the Abaqus job has completed before moving forward.

Below is some code that I have tried, one at a time:

```
os.popen('abaqus job=plate ask_delete=OFF')
```

```
os.system('abaqus job=plate ask_delete=OFF')
```

```
os.system('abaqus job=plate ask_delete=OFF')
```

```
subprocess.call('abaqus job=plate ask_delete=OFF',shell=True)
```

```
subprocess.check_call('abaqus job=plate ask_delete=OFF',shell=True)
```

I have also tried using the wait command after the subprocess tools like this:

```
p1 = subprocess.check_call('abaqus job=plate ask_delete=OFF',shell=True)
p1.wait()
```

But I get the error: `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'wait'`.

I do not want to use a `time.sleep()` as this causes a fair amount of down time in my code. I am using Python 3.5.2 and Anaconda 4.2.0 (64-bit).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to include the abaqus keyword "interactive". e.g.

`abaqus myjob=bob1 ask_delete=off interactive`

Otherwise it will run in the background and all output goes to `bob1.log` 
Also, there is a builtin python environment with the abaqus installation that can be used to automate running abaqus jobs. There are more options for job control and monitoring if you use this "abaqus" python

Comment: Thanks, I ran the code as subprocess.call('abaqus job=plate ask_delete=OFF interactive',shell=True).  I know that Abaqus has a python module but due to the mismatch in Python versions, I like the simplicity of just updating the .inp files and then submitting the jobs.

Answer (score 2):

Both functions `call(...)` and `check_call(...)` wait by default for the command to complete.
Just for debugging, call the command through Popen and run 'abaqus' with full path 'C:\...\abaqus.exe ...'.

```
import subprocess

cmd = subprocess.Popen('abaqus job=plate ask_delete=OFF', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
out, err = cmd.communicate()
code = cmd.returncode

print(code) # should 0 to indicate the command run successfully
print(out)  # what was piped to stdout
print(err)  # what was piped to stderr
```

Comment: Maurice, I copied your code in just as you had it and the python script now waits until the Abaqus job is complete before moving on.  I think this is because the cmd.communicate() command is holding up the script.  However, your comment sounds like you were just trying to debug the problem, just wanted to check if you intended this as a solution.

Comment: Great, if it works now. This was meant as a solution, personally i prefer Popen with correct parameters most.